# Replacing curl with python requests equivalent to POST a file to a server

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

After writing a file with the snippet below

```
    with open("temp.trig", "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

I use `curl` to load it into the server

```
curl -X POST -F file=@"temp.trig" -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8081/demo/upload
```

which works fine.

I am trying to replace the `curl` with python requests, as follows:

```
    with open("temp.trig", "rb") as f:
        result = requests.post("http://localhost:8081/demo/upload", files={'file': f},  
            headers = {"Accept": "application/json"})
```

which attempted to follow the `curl` as closely as possible.  This code results in an error 500 from the server.  I suspect it must be something related to the request, because the same server is ok via `curl.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check the server logs. Post the server response.

Answer (score 2):

There probably is nothing wrong with your `python` script.

Differences I've noticed between `curl` and `requests` are the following:

- obviously, `User-Agent` headers are different — `curl/7.47.0` vs. `python-requests/2.22.0`
- multipart boundary format in `Content-Type` header is different — `------------------------6debaa3504bbc177` in `curl` vs. `c1e9f4f617de4d0dbdb48fcc5aab67e0` in `requests`
- therefore `Content-Length` value will almost certainly be different
- `multipart/form-data` format in body is slightly different — `curl` adds an extra line (`Content-Type: text/plain`) before file contents

---

So depending on your file format, server may not be able to parse `requests` HTTP request format.

I think the best solution for you now is to compare raw HTTP requests from `curl` and `requests` and find what differences are significant.

For example:

1. Open terminal
2. Launch `netcat` with `nc -l -p 1234` command. This will listen to HTTP requests on `localhost` on port `1234` and output raw HTTP requests to terminal.
3. Send your `curl` request as it is to `localhost:1234` in another tab
4. Execute your `python` script as it is using URL `localhost:1234` in another tab
5. Compare raw requests from your `netcat` output

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

files = {
    'file': ('temp.trig', open('temp.trig', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('http://localhost:8081/demo/upload', headers=headers, files=files)
```

In case this doesn't work we really need to read more data on the server side, as Ivan Vinogradov explained well.

Comment: Please check my answer and, if it was useful, remember to upvote it and/or choose it as final answer.